# C# Unable to read XML file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, visual-studio

Im trying to read a xml file with the code as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<files>
   <pdf_input infolder ="C:\Users\Lambo\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\test\test\testPdfIn"
              outfolder ="C:\Users\Lambo\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\test\test\testPdfOut"
              autonameappend="_new" />


   <word_file infolder =" C:\Users\Lambo\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\test\test\testPdfIn"
              outfolder ="C:\Users\Lambo\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\test\test\testPdfOut" />


   <pdf_file fileRequired="true" directory="" autonameappend="pdf" />


   <docx_file fileRequired="true" directory="" autonameappend="docx" />

   <!-- autonameappend: Such as: (copy) -->


   <doc_file fileRequired="true" removePicture="true" removeFormfield="true"  directory="" autonameappend="_new" />


</files>
```

but some how the Im not able to read it. here is the code which im using to try to read the xml file.

```
public static void readConfig()
{
    try
    {
     //   StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("");
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("~/bin/config.xml");



        reader.MoveToContent();

        reader.ReadToDescendant("pdf_input");

        pdf_infolder = reader.GetAttribute("infolder");

        pdf_outfolder = reader.GetAttribute("outfolder");

        pdf_nameAppend = reader.GetAttribute("autonameappend");

        MessageBox.Show("two passed");



        word_outfolder = reader.GetAttribute("outfolder");          

        reader.ReadToNextSibling("pdf_file");
        pdf_required = Convert.ToBoolean(reader.GetAttribute("fileRequired"));
        pdf_newDirectoryV=reader.GetAttribute("directory");
        pdf_autoName = reader.GetAttribute("autonameappend");

        MessageBox.Show("3 passed");

        reader.ReadToNextSibling("docx_file");
        docx_required = Convert.ToBoolean(reader.GetAttribute("fileRequired"));
        docx_newDirectoryV=reader.GetAttribute("directory");
        docx_autoName = reader.GetAttribute("autonameappend");

        MessageBox.Show("4 passed");

        reader.ReadToNextSibling("doc_file");
        doc_required = Convert.ToBoolean(reader.GetAttribute("fileRequired"));
        doc_removePic = Convert.ToBoolean(reader.GetAttribute("removePicture"));
        doc_removeFF = Convert.ToBoolean(reader.GetAttribute("removeFormfield"));
        doc_newDirectoryV=reader.GetAttribute("directory");
        doc_autoName = reader.GetAttribute("autonameappend");

        reader.Close();

    //   MessageBox.Show("Success");

    //   MessageBox.Show("pdf_required is :" + pdf_required + "        pdf_newdirectory is :" + pdf_newDirectoryV + "End");

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("reading config file failed, using default value instead" );
        restoreDefault();
    }
}

private static void restoreDefault()
{

  //  wordName = @"C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SecureWord\SecureWord\bin\Debug\Sample3.doc";
    pdf_required = true;
    pdf_newDirectoryV = "";
    pdf_autoName = "";

    docx_required = true;
    docx_newDirectoryV = "";
    docx_autoName = "";

    doc_required = true;
    doc_removePic = true;
    doc_removeFF = true;
    doc_newDirectoryV = "";
    doc_autoName = "";

}
```

}

Anyhelp would be much appreciated Thanks alot!

Comment: How are you "not able to read it"?

Comment: It's giving me a ArgumentNullException when im trying to get the path of the infolder.

Answer (score 4):

```
new XmlTextReader("~/bin/config.xml")
```

The tilde path ([officially, "Web Application root operator"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx) only works for server controls and other ASP.NET aware utilities - not anywhere a path is needed.

You can use [`Server.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to get a physical location for the file.

```
new XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath("~/bin/config.xml"))
```

Comment: The file is a .CS file so i don't think i'll be able to use Server.MapPath in this case

Comment: Assuming you're running the .cs in ASP.NET, use HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath

Comment: What if the .cs is a console application, and im trying to get it read the xml file. and then use ASP.NET to call the cs file that reads the xml file

Comment: @SamuelTang - in a console app, you'd need to resolve the path yourself. Assuming the XML file is located next to the .EXE, you could just use "config.xml".

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to convert the relative ASP.NET path to a physical path. See [HttpServerUtility.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx).

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath("~/bin/config.xml"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I never used a XmlTextReader, go with this instead it seems alot easier to work with.

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.LoadXml("~path/mydoc.xml");
        foreach (XmlNode xNode in xDoc.ChildNodes)
        {
            //Do w.e
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq2Xml is easier to use

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(....);
var dict = xDoc.Element("files")
    .Descendants()
    .ToDictionary(k=>k.Name,v=>v.Attributes().ToDictionary(ak=>ak.Name,av=>av.Value));

foreach (var item in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key+":");
    foreach (var attr in item.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t"+attr.Key + "="+ attr.Value);
    }
}
```